# What is Uri string?

Tags: android

I was trying to build the sunshine app in udacity android development course. Anyway, what is "FORECAST_BASE_URL" here? what is URI string does? Is this like key word for Service provider?

this was how to built url in Sunshine

Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, locationQuery)
                .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                .build();

This was previous example;

Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(GITHUB_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_QUERY, githubSearchQuery)
                .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_SORT, sortBy)
                .build();

Comment: I find answer I was looking for here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937224/building-url-confusion-on-a-couple-of-lines       https://discussions.udacity.com/t/what-is-uri-string-in-building-url/388119

Answer (score 0):

A URI is short for Uniform Resource Identifier. This URI is a string that contains 1. The URL you are pointing towards, 2. The information you are trying to passover.

In the second Android code you supplied, you are building a URI string which asks to search for something (a file perhaps?) and if the result returns more than 1, the result should be sorted by any type of sorting technique (numerical, alphabetical) from a repository situated in github.

tldr; URI is to pass info over to the link you are targeting so the link could process and return the result of the info provided.

Comment: You can refer to  [URI - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) for a general of view of what is URI

Comment: Basicly I have no idea capital letter words mean and do.
FORECAST_BASE_URL
QUERY_PARAM, locationQuery
GITHUB_BASE_URL
they are not class or method So I dont understand them, If they are URI string, where can I find them while I am developing another app Since They are given to me in course material here.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, you can try to use the Log class to display variables so you can see what a code segment does. I believe the answer posted by Tahir has outlined your second question about all caps. [How to use Log for Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is a constant name. A constant name is usually written in capital letters when it is `final` and `static`. That means it is not going to change, you can not give another value to the same constant. 
Lets say :

```
final static String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "www.example.com";
```

> Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()

In your example a string constant is converted into a Uri variable.

I hope this is the answer to your question.